# Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^{0.3}}{x+1}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the equation:$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^{0.3}}{x+1}$$

I have no idea how to tackle this equation. I think it is related to hypergeometric functions but couldn't solve it.

Comment: Check your message for any typo. I don't think any teacher could give an exercise like this...

Comment: I faced this problem in a personal project...yeah , I suspected this would be messy solution...can you show the procedure? @Raffaele

Comment: the solution Looks ugly

Comment: I dont know if guessing the solution in a power series pattern then replacing it would help or not? I tried but its beyond my reach.

Comment: Note that we can write

$$\int \frac{x^{3/10}}{1+x}\,dx\overbrace{=}^{x=u^{10}}\int \frac{10u^{12}}{1+u^{10}}\,du$$which can be solved painstakingly using partial fraction expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enforcing the substitution $x=u^{10}$ reveal

$$\begin{align}
\int \frac{x^{3/10}}{1+x}\,dx&=\int \frac{10u^{12}}{1+u^{10}}\,du\\\\
&=10\int u^2\,du- 10\int \frac{u^2}{1+u^{10}}\,du\\\\
&=\frac{10}{3}u^3-10\int \frac{u^2}{1+u^{10}}\,du\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Using partial fraction expansion, the integrand of the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ becomes

$$\frac{u^2}{1+u^{10}}=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac{a_n}{u-u_n}$$

where $u_n=e^{i(2n-1)\pi/10}$ and $a_n=\frac{1}{10u_n^7}=-\frac{u_n^3}{10}$.  Using this expansion, we have

$$\begin{align}
10\int \frac{u^2}{1+u^{10}}\,du&=-\sum_{n=1}^{10}u_n^3\int \frac{1}{u-u_n}\,du\\\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^{10}u_n^3\log(u-u_n)
\end{align}$$

Finally, we have

$$\int \frac{x^{3/10}}{1+x}\,dx=\frac{10}{3}x^{3/10}+\sum_{n=1}^{10}u_n^3 \log(x^{1/10}-u_n)+C$$